# Pipenv failure Resolution Impossible

Tags: python, pipenv, python-3.9

I am running into a problem with dependency installation problem with pipenv and the stack trace isn't telling me much. So, I am a little clueless as to where/what to look for. It mentions 2 "transient" constraint files and since they are transient, they are gone (not in the path anymore), once the error is thrown.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to debug this properly.

Error when doing `pipenv lock`

```
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
 Locking...Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Success!
Warning: C:\foldername\airflow-plugins\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Locking [packages] dependencies...
 Locking...Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!

CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Cannot install -r C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv_sifl2kxrequirements\pipenv-mr1tm8x5-constraints.txt (line 13) and -r C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv_sifl2kxrequirements\pipenv-mr1tm8x5-constraints.txt (line 15) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 820, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 769, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\resolver.py", line 749, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\abc\appdata\roaming\python\python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 1082, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\abc\appdata\roaming\python\python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 876, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:\users\abc\appdata\roaming\python\python310-32\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 677, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

There is a `warning` about urllib3 and chardet but that seems to be only a warning and I did try to update the `requests` package as some of the S.O posts suggested. Also tried `pipenv lock --pre`

This is how my Pipfile looks (I have masked some internal url and packages). If needed, I can also provide the dependencies of the internal packages , used in this Pipfile.

I just am looking for pointers to how to debug this.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://artifactoryurl/api/pypi/python/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "artifactory-pypi"

[packages]
apache-airflow = "==1.10.14"
azure-identity = "*"
azure-storage-file-datalake = "*"
pyodbc = "*"
PySmbClient = "*"
msal = "*"
msrestazure = "*"
asyncio = "*"
some internal package = ">=2.0.20"
wtforms = "==2.3.3"
sqlalchemy = "==1.3.20"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.4.4"
"some internal package" = "*"
databricks-sql-connector = "==2.1.0"
markupsafe = "==2.0.1"
protobuf= "==3.20.*"

[dev-packages]
pre-commit = "==2.16.0"
black = "==21.12b0"
isort = "==5.10.1"
mypy = "==0.930"
flake8 = "==4.0.1"
mccabe = "==0.6.1"
flake8-docstrings = "==1.6.0"
flake8-bugbear = "==21.11.29"
flake8-absolute-import = "==1.0.0.1"
pytest = "==6.2.5"
pytest-cov = "==3.0.0"
pytest-env = "==0.6.2"
"punch.py" = "==2.0.0"
yamllint = "==1.26.3"
mock = "==4.0.3"

[requires]

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Comment: I had encountered a similar situation on ubuntu. I uninstalled specified urllib3 and chardet versions and re-installed their matching versions.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Now, when I try to uninstall packages, I get a failure in the asyncio package saying ``` future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
````

Comment: So, I am assuming it is something with the asyncio package and the python version that I have (3.9.7)

Comment: Given your error messages above, it seems that some of your dependencies are incompatible. As `asyncio = "*"`, then it installs the latest package, which might cause a problem. In my case, incompatible versions were headaches, it should be in your case too. You need to find the matching versions. Just try `pipenv graph` as the message suggests. It will tell you which package versions are required against which versions are installed.